# Why does the Moon not rotate about its axis, relative to Earth's rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, moon, tidal-effect

One of the common features of the Moon is the fact that only one face of the Moon is ever visible from Earth, regardless of how much of its orbit the moon has made about the Earth.

This would imply that the rotation of the moon about its axis relative to Earth's rotation is zero/very small. This seems like a very unlikely phenomenon that would arise randomly.

So, how did this lack of rotation arise? Is it the result of the means that the Moon was formed, or could it perhaps be caused by tidal effects due to the Earth's gravity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4116/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes, that link answers it. My bad